# Python move from attribute to his class

Tags: python, function, class, attributes

Suppose I have this code:

```
class abc():

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0


def somefunc(var):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    aaa = abc()
    somefunc(aaa.a)
```

Now my question, there is a way to get an instance of the class (aaa) by his attribute (a) that passed to "somefunc" if I have only the attribute? In other words, to move from attribute to his class.

I know that is not popular to do that but I have some situation that forces me to.

Thank you for help!!!!

Comment: Please format your code correctly

Comment: Im writing from my phone and its complicated, the code is very short and simple so...

Comment: It may be short but indentation is very important in python.

Comment: In general, no. In the specific case in your code, definitely no, because the parameter is probably passed by value.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I get the essence of your question. What is the code that you want to write and what is the behavior that you want and what is the behavior, that you get?

I have one interpretation of your question, but not sure, that's the correct one.
you want to call `somefunc` such, that it with` aaa.a` as param and you want, that `somefunc` can change the attribute `a` of the object `aaa`.

This is not possible if `a` is a simple value like for example an int a string, a float, bool.

Comment: If `aaa.a` were a list, a dict, a set, a class instance, then you could change the contents of the list, dict, set or attributes of the object.

Thus you can write a function which changes the contents of a list which is passed to, but if you want a function to change an int you write it differently.

So two choices for somefunc

`aaa.a = somefunc(aaa.a)`  you receive an int and you return the new int value

or
`somefunc(aaa)`   you receive aaa ond somefunc changes directly aaa.a

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

Suppose I have this code:

```
class abc():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = []


def somefunc(var):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    aaa = abc()
    bbb = abc()
    bbb.a = aaa.a
    somefunc(aaa.a)
```

Now should somefunc determine that it should refer to aaa or bbb?

Answer (score 0):

You can if you really want to, but I wouldn't advise it.

```
class abc():
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

def somefunc(value):
    vars_dict = globals()         # swap this for whatever dictionary of variables you wish to use 
    abcs = [vars_dict[i] for i in vars_dict if isinstance(vars_dict[i],abc)]
    return [instance for instance in abcs if instance.a == value]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance1 = abc(1)
    instance2 = abc(2)
    instance3 = abc(1)
    print('1s: {}'.format(str(somefunc(1))))
    print('2s: {}'.format(str(somefunc(2))))
    print('3s: {}'.format(str(somefunc(3))))
```

This grabs from `vars_dict` all instances with which `instance.a == value`. I've implemented the globals() dict here, but you can swap it out for another dictionary as is appropriate.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use instance as a parameter.

```
class abc():

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.a = num

def somefunc(var):
    print(var.a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    aaa = abc(2)
    somefunc(aaa)
    bbb = abc(4)
    somefunc(bbb)
```